# Setting default language

Tags: xamarin.ios

I would like to see default button captions in my native language ,

Even I changed iPad's language to another lang. my app still shows English ones...Edit,Done,Save etc.

I also set CFBundleDevelopmentRegion as a User-Defined variable in XCode but not helped !

Can you help ?

Comment: Did you try to set Local settings (not language settings)? Also, you saw "Edit,Done,Save" on a XIB-interfaces or code-created?

Comment: Yeah,sure both of them are the same. But doesn't effect for my app. buttons. Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should make these things:

- Add your native language to app's supported `Localization` array of languages; [image: how it looks like in app settings]
- Make your `Application.Main` procedure looks like:

```cs
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
        // you can specify it here.
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetValueForKey(NSArray.FromStrings("tr"), new NSString("AppleLanguages"));
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
        UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
```

Then, this

[image]

turns to this

[image]

(I suggested that your language is turkish.)

Comment: I can't add a Localization. When I click on + button to add there is a dialog let me choose localization file. But I do not have, I don't try to localise it. I had also tried the code you shared for main class but didn't helped sadly.

Comment: Did you tried to set app's settings via double click on `Info.plist` file?, then went to Advanced Tab? If it doesn't help, try to edit it as text file. Example (taken from my project):  <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>   
 <array>
  <string>English</string>
  <string>Russian</string>
  <string>German</string>
 </array>     As you can see on screenshots, it works.

Comment: Ohh lastly, When I add English secondly and added mideast langs it worked!

Comment: Hey! It's funny that app should have at least 2 languages to that stuff working.

Comment: I think so ! But it worth's to use it. I like XCode Storyboard and design features but hate Objective C. So Xamarin make things better for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For monotouch I think it is different,
They hide some langs for reducing the size of IPA.

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/localization_and_internationalization